# Bottle neck in using Activemq

Tags: activemq-classic

I am working on a project which uses activemq as broker.
My problem is that there are many request and many data to be put on Activemq queue. Is there a way to somehow have more than one Activemq instance?I know that we can have multiple instance.But I don't know how to manage them, that when one broker is busy, we use the ther instance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are multiple ways you can scale. The best way is hard to tell with so little information about your case.

Add more resources to the broker server may be one solution.

Another may be to create multiple instances and connect them with network of brokers. Make sure you simply not duplicate all messages to two brokers, but distribute consumers among the brokers and only pipe published messages between broker. Your milage may vary.

You may find the `rebalanceClusterClients` on the transport connector convenient to automatically distribute clients in your cluster. However, there is no magic - you need optimize for your own scenario.